# Receive and save ajax posted image within c #

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, image, post

I'm new to development, so please excuse my ignorance.  I'm using a cropper.js example to post a cropped image to an internal server.  I need to receive the post on the server side and save the data as an image.  My cropper function is below:

```
          document.getElementById('crop').addEventListener('click', function () {
              var initialAvatarURL;
              var canvas;

              $modal.modal('hide');

              if (cropper) {
                  canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                      width: 160,
                      height: 160,
                  });
                  initialAvatarURL = avatar.src;
                  avatar.src = canvas.toDataURL();
                  $progress.show();
                  $alert.removeClass('alert-success alert-warning');
                  canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                      var formData = new FormData();

                      formData.append('avatar', blob, 'avatar.jpg');
                      $.ajax('http://localhost:1233/http://localhost:1234/test', {
                          method: 'POST',
                          data: formData,
                          processData: false,
                          contentType: false,

                          xhr: function () {
                              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                              xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                                  var percent = '0';
                                  var percentage = '0%';

                                  if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                      percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                                      percentage = percent + '%';
                                      $progressBar.width(percentage).attr('aria-valuenow', percent).text(percentage);
                                  }
                              };

                              return xhr;
                          },

                          success: function () {
                              $alert.show().addClass('alert-success').text('Upload success');
                          },

                          error: function () {
                              avatar.src = initialAvatarURL;
                              $alert.show().addClass('alert-warning').text('Upload error');
                          },

                          complete: function () {
                              $progress.hide();
                          },
                      });
                  });
              }
```

I'm using the cors-anywhere nodejs proxy do deal with the cors issues for testing.  I have a listener example in c# below:

```
namespace httplistenerexample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartServer();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void StartServer()
        {
            var httpListener = new HttpListener();
            var simpleServer = new SimpleServer(httpListener, "http://127.0.0.1:1234/test/", ProcessYourResponse);
            simpleServer.Start();
        }

        public static byte[] ProcessYourResponse(string test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test);
            return new byte[0]; // TODO when you want return some response
        }

        public delegate byte[] ProcessDataDelegate(string data);

        public class SimpleServer
        {
            private const int HandlerThread = 2;
            private readonly ProcessDataDelegate handler;
            private readonly HttpListener listener;

            public SimpleServer(HttpListener listener, string url, ProcessDataDelegate handler)
            {
                this.listener = listener;
                this.handler = handler;
                listener.Prefixes.Add(url);
            }

            public void Start()
            {
                if (listener.IsListening)
                    return;

                listener.Start();

                for (int i = 0; i < HandlerThread; i++)
                {
                    listener.GetContextAsync().ContinueWith(ProcessRequestHandler);
                }
            }

            public void Stop()
            {
                if (listener.IsListening)
                    listener.Stop();
            }

            private void ProcessRequestHandler(Task<HttpListenerContext> result)
            {
                var context = result.Result;

                if (!listener.IsListening)
                    return;

                // Start new listener which replace this
                listener.GetContextAsync().ContinueWith(ProcessRequestHandler);

                // Read request
                string request = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

                // Prepare response
                var responseBytes = handler.Invoke(request);
                context.Response.ContentLength64 = responseBytes.Length;

                var output = context.Response.OutputStream;
                output.WriteAsync(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
                output.Close();
            }

        }




    }
}
```

I can see the image data on the screen through the console.writeline in the ProcessYourResponse method, but cannot seem to figure out how to retrieve the data and save it as a file.  I am currently posting the data as a blob, so it seems I would need to use a stream to retrieve binary data.  Is that the best way, or should I post the data as a base64 string and retrieve it using a streamreader.  In short, I need the ProcessYourResponse method to save the image data to a file.  I could really use some help as I've been fighting this for weeks now.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are using http and you only can send binary data either by adding as a mime attachment, or sending as a base64 string.  Creating a base64 string takes time and the converted data is larger than the original binary data.  Your retrieve method has to be the same as your send method.  The code also looks like you are using XMLHttpRequest.  So first decide how you want to send  See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so if my base64 image source looks like this: src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...SUhE9Ko5SAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"  how to I format it into the formData element?

Comment: You have to do two steps.  First take you base64 string and convert to bytes.  Then create a bitmap from the bytes.